# angular2 rxjs way to check forkJoin completely done

Tags: angular, rxjs

I was wondering if there is some rxjs operation i can call after forkJoin to know if my parallel async tasks have completed, so I  can have something like *ngIf="loaded | async" an in angular2 template.

I came up with one solution but it seems messy to me.
I bet there is a cleaner rxJS way of doing this.

plunkr if you need it:
https://plnkr.co/edit/UFVCJpjKAEGguMls5eIl?p=preview

```
public loaded:Observable<boolean>;

constructor(private http:Http) {
    // This is the best solution I could come up with. Is there a cleaner way
    // by just calling some operation after forkJoin instead of building my own observable?
    this.loaded = Observable.create((observer) => {
        observer.next(false);
        Observable.forkJoin(
            this.something1(),
            this.something2(),
            () => {
                // now we know we have finished
                observer.next(true);
            }
        ).subscribe();
    });
}

something1() {
    return this.http.get('test1.json').map((res) => res.json());
}

something2() {
    return this.http.get('test2.json').map((res) => res.json());
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Based on Luka's comment, tried this. works great. much nicer:

```
this.loaded = Observable.combineLatest(
    this.something1(),
    this.something2(),
    () => {
        // now we know we have finished
        return true
    }
);
```

Comment: I think you can `combineLatest` the two and then `map` to a Boolean.

Comment: You are right! Much better. thank you.

Comment: No problem, I wrote an answer, how I would do it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `combineLatest`. Something like this should work:

```
this.loaded = this.something1().combineLatest(
    this.something2(),
    function (s1, s2) { return true }
).take(1);
```

Also notice, that I call `take(1)` at the end, to ensure we only emit one event, since it'll only be loaded once.

Comment: thanks. i'm new to rxjs and it's so hard to know...when i get stuff working...am i doing it a dumb way or a good way? in time i'll know but for now..i really don't

Comment: Don't worry about it, it takes time for everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be more straightforward:

```
this.loaded = Observable.forkJoin(this.something1(), this.something2()).map(_=>true);
```

Comment: I actually had tried this but it failed..because my real something1 and something2 returned observable's that had their own map functions which didn't return anything. once i changed something1 and 2's observables' map functions to return true (or anything) it worked.